# How to insert a row from one table to another table using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am having to two tables `Data_Cust_Log` and `Data_Cust`.The structure of both the table is same.When a customer is authorized the row of data for that customer from `Data_Cust_Log` needs to be copied to `Data_Cust`.Can anybody let me know if this can be done using `Linq to SQL`.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objects are of the same type:

```cs
 using (DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
 {
    var data = context.Data_Cust_Log.Where(x => x.CustomerID == 12) Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    context.Data_Cust.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    context.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

If they are not of the same type:

```cs
using (DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var data = context.Data_Cust_Log.Where(x => x.CustomerID == 12) Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();

    Data_Cust_Object = new Data_Cust_Object {CustomerID = data.CustomerID, Price = data.Price}; //and so on 

    context.Data_Cust.InsertOnSubmit(Data_Cust_Object);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: ,objects not of same type ?Could not understand.And what is => , never used it.Can you explain a bit.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @freebird => is used to iterate through elements in lambda expressions. When you create new linq to sql classes file .dbml and copy your tables in it you will get new classes that each corresponds to your table Row for each table, so if you created file through VS L2S designer you will have two different objects for your two tables so you should use solution #2

Comment: I am using DataClasses1DataContext , so can I say that both the objects are same.

Comment: @freebird They will be different beacuse they come from two different tables, but their properties will be the same if they are exactly the same in your db. I made up this line `context.Data_Cust_Log.Where(x => x.CustomerID == 12)` In case you have field CustomerID this code would get customer with customerID of 12 in `var data`, next line would create new object fro your second table `Data_Cust` and copy properties to it in curly braces and last two lines would insert it into second table.

Comment: @user1010650 The second line in curly braces , you mention values explicitly , I have huge no of columns , do I need to mention it.

Comment: @freebird Yes you will have to do that

Comment: Ok will try and let you know.Thanks for your help.I could even write Sql insert may be , if I need to write for every column.May be insert into Data_Cust select from Data_Cust_Log could be ok too.